# How to desynchronize LED lighting refresh (blink / flicker) rates?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led

LED lighting drives a couple members of my family insane. The refresh rate is horrible and we are rather sensitive to it.  It becomes markedly worse when dimming LEDs are used at lower levels.

How can one change the sync rate between lights so that the various bulbs "fire" at different intervals?

It seems as though one should be able to add a small circuit or capacitor to the bulb sockets that would desynchronize the lights so that they are going off and on at different times and thus the refresh rate would appear as constant to the observer...

Comment: Are you using capacitive dropper or switching driver LED lamps? The two types have very different flicker properties especially when dimmed...

Comment: That's a very good question, I don't know the details of these LED bulbs.  Here they are on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01DEZ19I4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1